# Detection and recognition text from Tyres (python)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, text, deep-learning, computer-vision

Hi i have bunch of images of tyres, we need to detect and recognize the text on the tyres, 
here i am facing difficulties to detect the text, because the text and background of the tyre are same, i have tried with EAST text detector and yolo text detector ( without own data train ),
is there any better solutions to detect the text from these kind of background images

[image: tyre1]
[image: tyre2]

here i need to detect only the 10 digit serial number like "75R-0006884"

edit: pre processed image
[image: thresolded image]

Answer (score 0):

Some preprocessing before passing the images in through a non-retrained deep network might help! Try binarizing/grayscaling the image and playing with those thresholds to see what gives maximum contrast.

But I gotta say, you might have to retrain an existing network to achieve good performance.

Comment: I have tried with pretrained east text detector. But it wasn't worked and not able to use imagemorphological or thresholds due to same background

Comment: You might want to try a letter detector instead maybe. Since these are tire markings, you have information about tire ratings you can leverage: for example, there are only so many ratings possible. If you know one of the letters in a rating, you can guess what the others are. Similarly, there maybe a fixed number of "numbers" after the "R". You can try and individual letter detector instead. 

Natural scenes tend to be tough and require a lot of morphological processing beforehand. Can you share examples of contrast adjustment (CLAHE), binarizing etc?

Comment: Cant send entire code in comments. I jist tried opencv erossion dilation and thresholdings none of even able to differentiate the text from background

Comment: No, I don't mean the code. Can you share processed images of the two sample images above? So we can take a look at what kind of preprocessing might help.

Comment: hello sai krishna, i have added the pre processed  images, kindly check